# list index is out of range in try/raise/exception

Tags: python-2.7, indexoutofrangeexception, index-error

I have the following code:

```
for i in range(len(str(hoursList))):
    try:
        g(hoursList[i])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(nameList[i]) + " " + "has more than 80 hours worked!")
```

When I run the code, I get an error saying "IndexError: list index out of range". I'm wondering if its because I have hoursList[i], but when I take out the [i], the loop runs too many times.
My nameList and hoursList has the following in it, respectively.

['Michael Johnson', 'Sue Jones', 'Tom Spencer', 'Mary Harris', 'Alice Tolbert', 'Joe Sweeney', 'Linda Smith', 'Ted Farmer', 'Ruth Thompson', 'Bob Bensen']
[8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 8.75, 11.0, 11.0, 5.25, 5.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening when you are doing `len(str(hoursList))` is you are turning the entire list into a string then going through and returning an `i` for each number, space, and `,` of the new string. For example:

`len(str(["hello", "world"])) == 18`

But if you do this:

`len(["hello", "world"]) == 2`

So when you are in the `for i` loop you end up going over how many entries are actually in the `hoursList`.

Change your loop to be:

```
for i in range(len(hoursList)):
    try:
        g(hoursList[i])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(nameList[i]) + " " + "has more than 80 hours worked!")
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize I was turning my list into a string @PeterH